# I can't import from flask_sqlalchemy and from flask_wtf.csrf even though I did pip install for both. It was working before I got a new pc

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

The error when I run run.py is from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

I am using windows 11 and visual studio code. All the other imports are working.

When I type pip freeze --local I get

```
bcrypt==3.2.0
cffi==1.15.0
click==8.0.3
colorama==0.4.4
csrf==0.1b1
Flask==2.0.2
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==0.15.1
greenlet==1.1.2
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
pycparser==2.20
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.26
Werkzeug==2.0.2
WTForms==2.3.3
```

I have tried pip uninstall and pip install for both flask_sqlalchemy and flask_wtf.csrf.

if you want I can upload the entire code to github.

To setup the virtual environment I follow the steps from this link .
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask
To install the virtual environment

I even checked the environment variables
Here is the path
C:\Users\nmyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310

Here are the environment variables.
C:\Users\nmyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
C:\Users\nmyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\

Oddly enough when I click on the non recommended virtual environment
Everything works but flask-login.
[list of virtual environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG8DX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check which pip you are using through the `pip --version` command.

It looks like, you have selected the virtual environment, but you have not installed the pip module on it, so it will use the global pip. Then modules will be installed on the global one, but the python interpreter was the virtual environment, so it will output ModuleNotFoundError.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the virtual environment in your console before running pip

```
source ./venv/Scripts/activate
```

Comment: I did it shows venv in green and I thought it is ```./venv/Scripts/activate``` not ```source ./venv/Scripts/activate```

Comment: It's source if you are using git bash.

Comment: I don't think it is source. Or at least it is not working here.
```source : The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ source ./venv/Scripts/activate
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException```

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions? I tried what you suggested.